# Solve a system of three equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x=\dfrac{a-.5c+.25d}{a+c+d}$

$y=\dfrac{.5c\sqrt{3}+.25d\sqrt{3}}{a+c+d}$

$z=a+c+2d$

How do I make it so that only an $x$, an $y$, and/or and $z$ are on the Right-Hand-Side of the equation while only $a$, $c$, or $d$ is on the Left-Hand-Side?

This should look like:

"$a=equation$"

"$c=equation$"

"$d=equation$"

This is a point on a 3d graph. the point is always within a triangle.

$\triangle acd$

$a=(1,0)$

$c=(-.5,-.5\times{\sqrt{3}})$

$d=(.25,.25\times{\sqrt{3}})$

The $z$ coordinate will be between $0$ and $255$ for $a$ and $c$, but $d$ is between $0$ and $510$.

Originally this was a quadrilateral and point $b$(not previously mentioned) doesn't affect the math within this triangle.

Some similar questions have been solved using matrices, but I always get he wrong answer when I try to do them.

This is what I have so far. I have little time to work on this:

from $z$:

$a=z-c-2d$

$c=z-a-2d$

$d=\dfrac{z-a-c}{2}$

$0=a+c+2d-z$

From $x$:

$a=\dfrac{.5c(-2x-1)}{x-1}-.25d$

$c=\dfrac{a(4-4x)+d(1-4x)}{2+4x}$

$d=\dfrac{4a(1-x)-2c(1-2x)}{4x-1}$

$0=(4x-4)a+(4x+2)c+(4x-1)d$

From y:

$a=(c(.5*\sqrt(3) - y) + d(.25*\sqrt(3) - y))/y$

$c=(d(.25*\sqrt(3) - y) - ya)/(y - .5*\sqrt(3))$

$d=(c(.5*\sqrt(3) - y) - ya)/(y - .25*\sqrt(3))$

$0=(4y)a+(4y-2*\sqrt{3})c+(4y-\sqrt{3})d$

combined:

$0=(4x-4y-5)a+(4x-4y+1+2*\sqrt{3})c+(4x-4y+1+\sqrt{3})d-z$

Comment: Is $d2$ supposed to be $2d$? or maybe $d^2$? or something else? Anyway, clear fractions, combine like terms, and solve the resulting system (if it's linear).

Comment: $2d$ is $d2$ but to be more clear $d\times{2}$

Comment: The first equation is $4x(a+c+d)=4a-2c+d$, which is $(4x-4)a+(4x+2)c+(4x-1)d=0$.  Similarly the other two equations can be rewritten in the form $Pa+Qc+Rd=S$ for some coefficients $P,Q,R,S$ not involving $a,c,d$. So you get three linear equations in the three unknowns, $a,c,d$.  Do you know how to solve such a system?

Comment: I'm in the middle of just rearranging the equations myself. I'm not sure how the $P, Q, R, S$ makes this easier. I'm not sure how to solve that.

Comment: OK. Let me know when you have the equations rearranged. By the way, if you want to be certain that I see a comment, you should put @Gerry into it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok

Comment: Still working at it?

Comment: Yep. After some deck sanding and wasp nest removal.

Comment: I'm a little stuck now.

Comment: Why not try doing what I suggested several comments up? Did you see the steps I took to rewrite the 1st equation in the form $Pa+Qc+Rd=S$ where the coefficients $P,Q,R,S$ didn't involve the unknowns $a,c,d$? Can you do the same thing for the 2nd equation?

Comment: $(4x-4)a+(4x+2)c+(4x-1)d=S$ for $x$. $(4y+0)a+(4y-2\times{\sqrt{3}})c+(4y-\sqrt{3})d=S$ for $y$. and I don't know how to write $z$ as $Pa+Qb+Qc=S$ and then how to solve it. Can you give a reference? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Look at what I wrote for the 1st equation. Now, look at what you wrote. See the difference? Also, I didn't say, "write $z$ as $Pa+Qc+Rd=S$"; I said, "rewrite the 3rd equation in the form, $Pa+Qc+Rd=S$. $P,Q,R,S$ are allowed to involve $x,y,z$, but not $a,c,d$. If you look at the 3rd equation, there's actually nothing to do --- it's already written in the form we need. So, now, can you write the three equations in the form I am suggesting?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It may or may not be of interest to you that this question has now been reopened. (In case it is, I wanted to make sure that you know.)

Comment: In your most recent edit, you have set a $3\times3$ matrix, a vector, and a number equal. This makes no sense. If you want to do it with matrices, what you are aiming for is a $3\times3$ matrix, multiplied by the vector of unknowns, equal a vector of known quantites.

Comment: Are you back to sanding your deck?

Comment: Yep. and now travel for my job, on top of that. just no time for me.